# searching for MethodInvocation through eclipse AST

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree

I am writing an Eclipse plug-in for code formatting and I need to detect method invocations in the AST but I cant seem to do it.
I currently using the getNodeType() but it returns EXPRESSION_STATEMENT and when I debug I see that it's expression type is indeed a method invocation yet it still returns an EXPRESSION_STATEMENT type.

(I know i am missing a couple of checks but It doesnt matter currently, assume the Then statement and the Else statement is only one command of system.out.println() )

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

```
static boolean treatIfMethod(final AST ast, final ASTRewrite r, final IfStatement node){
  final ASTNode thenMethod=(ASTNode)((Block)node.getThenStatement()).statements().get(0),
          elseMethod=(ASTNode)((Block)node.getElseStatement()).statements().get(0);
  if (thenMethod.getNodeType()==ASTNode.METHOD_INVOCATION &&
          elseMethod.getNodeType()==ASTNode.METHOD_INVOCATION){
      ...
      }
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `getExpression()` method of the `ExpressionStatement` to get the expression the statement represents. This should be the `MethodInvocation` you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! no one works with AST so info on them is pretty scarce and not really organized